# Prove that $ b^\frac{1}{n} − a^\frac{1}{n} < (b − a)^\frac{1}{n}$ , for $0 < a < b$ and $n ≥ 2$.

Tags: analysis, inequality, logic

Hello dear Mathematics community, I'm currently studying for my Analysis I exam and have stumbled across the following inequality:

Prove that $ b^\frac{1}{n} − a^\frac{1}{n} < (b − a)^\frac{1}{n}$, for $0 < a < b$ and $n ≥ 2$.

I've been trying to prove the inequality for hours, but I always get stuck at some point, no matter what approach I choose. I feel like I'm missing a decisive piece of the puzzle...

Furthermore I've searched through this and other mathematics forums and have found no solution to the problem.

Any kind of help is very much appreciated!

Comment: $(x+y)^{p} \leq x^{p}+y^{p}$ for $0<p<1$, $x, y \geq 0$. See if you can find this online.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how does that apply to this inequality?

Comment: @Ramanujan figured that out already, not enough to prove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First some manipulation:
$$b^{1/n}-a^{1/n}<(b-a)^{1/n}$$
$$\iff b^{1/n}<a^{1/n}+(b-a)^{1/n} $$
$$\iff b< (a^{1/n}+(b-a)^{1/n})^n$$
Call now $x:= a^{1/n}$, $y=(b-a)^{1/n}$. You can rewrite the above expression as
$$x^n+y^n<(x+y)^n,$$
which I think should be much easier to verify (note that both $x$ and $y$ are strictly positive).

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much.

Comment: Nice! Perhaps add '${\iff}$' in front of lines 3 & 4, for maximum clarity.